# How to edit remote text file in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-io

I have a text file in one server(ubuntu), how can I edit it remotely in ror application.

I'm thinking it should be done by:

Downloading the remote file to local tmp folder.

Edit the file using

`File.open(params[:file_path], 'a') { |f| f.write("#{params[:token]}\n") }`

And then upload it to the remote server

```
Net::SSH.start(remote_server_ip, "root", {:password => "secret"}) do |ssh|
  ssh.scp.upload! localfile_path, remote_file_path
end
```

I want to know is this the best approach or is there any other way OR any ruby gems.

I have already built logic to add/remove line in local machine.

I want this to work for remote file.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Why not do that write to file operation within the ssh session itself?

Comment: Can I maintain ssh session in web? Actually I will be downloading the file and show it in the view, then user could edit its content, when he clicks save I'm saving it in local and then uploading that file to remote server. Is it possible to maintain ssh session in this scenario?? I'm asking because I don't know about it.

Comment: What do you mean "in web"? It should be in controller/model, right?

Comment: yeah. Its in controller. I thought you were referring to ruby script file.

Comment: You'll have to create separate ssh connections for Showing and Editing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach sounds good to me. The net/scp gem makes it easy to reuse your existing ssh connection for download upload like this:

```
require 'net-ssh'
require 'net-scp'
ssh = Net::SSH.start('my-server', 'my-user')
ssh.scp.download!('/remote/path/to/file', '/local/destination/folder')
(do stuff with file)
ssh.scp.upload!('/local/modified/file', '/remote/path/to/file')
```

Note that you need to install both the `net/ssh` and `net/scp` gems.